# jh.jar and old Sun signature

Tags: java, jar, digital-signature, java-web-start

I'm working with JWS application. This application has a user manual and it use jh.jar-file. In jh.jar, there is Sun digital signature (validity 2002-2003), so the application show warning dialog after start (The digital signature has expired). Is it legal to delete Sun signature and use own to sign that file or is there any new updates of that file (with validity 2013-2014 signature)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use unsigned (but youngest) version of jh.jar, like [JavaHelp 2.0.05](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.help/javahelp/2.0.05)